# Changing transform state on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

So I have some css code like this

```
    .some_class{
        width: 30%;
        height: 120px;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-top: 100px;
        float: left;
        @include boxShadowLevel(2);
        transition: box-shadow 0.4s, transform 0.4s;

        transform: scale(0);

        &:nth-child(odd):hover{
            transform: translate(-3px, -3px) scale(1.1);
            @include boxShadowLevel(3);
        }

        &:nth-child(even):hover{
            transform: translate(3px, -3px) scale(1.1);
            @include boxShadowLevel(3);
        }

        // Some more css here (which is not relevant for the question)

    }
```

As you can see the standard transform is scale(0) and thats because I fade it in with some js code onload

```
$(elem[i]).css("transform", "scale(1)")
```

The problem is that the hover changes nothing and I suspect, that it is because of the initial transform.

Is there any solution to this, without a second wrapper div or anything like that?

Comment: Could you show us the accompanying markup?  Also, is there a reason why you need to use JS for this `scale` transform and not a straightforward CSS transform like you've used for the `translate` transform?

Comment: the html is huge, but it has no relevance (no style tags, did work before, ...). I did use js so I can do the animation when everything is loaded +0.2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
This is my SCSS (note the added "show")

```
.some_class{
    width: 30%;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    float: left;
    @include boxShadowLevel(2);
    transition: box-shadow 0.4s, transform 0.4s;

    transform: scale(0);

    &.show{
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    &:nth-child(odd):hover{
        transform: translate(-3px, -3px) scale(1.1);
        @include boxShadowLevel(3);
    }

    &:nth-child(even):hover{
        transform: translate(3px, -3px) scale(1.1);
        @include boxShadowLevel(3);
    }

    // Some more css here (which is not relevant for the question)

}
```

And then adding the class "show" instead of setting the transform manually in js code:

```
$(elem[i]).addClass("show")
```